# Trigger a function based on the presence of an audio tone

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

We are developing a web app that will monitor an audio stream for a 2.5 second, 35hz tone on the left channel. The tone will be used to trigger a function, specifically to mute the audio stream for 30 seconds. I've been reading through the WebAudio API but haven't found a scenario similar to this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Lookup the AnalyserNode which is part of the WebAudio API

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually on the page right now so hopefully that means I'm going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different ways to do this.  How you decide to do it depends on several things including on when you want to be able to trigger the silence.  Do want to produce silence as soon as you detect the 35 Hz tone?  When the 35 Hz tone ends?  Is the tone the only audio on the left channel?  (That makes it much easier.)

You can use an `AnalyserNode` as mentioned, but detecting a 35 Hz tone could be difficult since you might need a fairly large FFT size which incurs delay.

Another possibility is to use a bandpass [`BiquadFilterNode`](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#biquadfilternode) to filter out everything except the 35 Hz tone.  (May need more than one such filter.  This becomes a filter design problem).  Then if there's any output from the filter and if it's large enough, you know there's a 35 Hz tone.  You can look at the output of the filter using a `ScriptProcessorNode` or `AudioWorkletNode` or `AnalyserNode` (examining the time-domain data).

Another method is to use a [matched filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter).  Create a 35 Hz tone and save it in an `AudioBuffer`.  Use a `ConvolverNode` (with [normalization disabled](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-convolveroptions-disablenormalization)).  Connect the left channel to the convolver and look at the output (using ScriptProcessor/AudioWorklet/Analyser).  When the output is large enough, you know you have a 35 Hz tone.

Finally, you could do all of the analysis of finding the tone by writing up your analysis code in a ScriptProcessorNode or AudioWorkletNode.

I've left out quite a bit of detail, but this might be good enough to get you started.  Follow up if you need more details.

Comment: Thanks, this is great advice and you've given me a lot to try. To answer your first question the silence will be triggered immediately upon detecting the tone. When the tone ends there will continue to be audio on the channel. We are a radio station and the tone is used solely to notify affiliate stations that they can break away to perform their station ID. Today we use physical hardware to perform this with larger affiliates but we are looking for a web app approach as a free solution for smaller stations.

Comment: If you know how the hardware works, you could possibly create an equivalent version in WebAudio. The nice thing about that is that the web version will behave just like the HW version. I know of one person who took the schematics of a Marshall guitar amp and recreated it in software with WebAudio.  People tell me it sounds just like the real Marshall amp.